# How do I rearrange words separated with comma (txt file) to list of words in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, txt

I have a txt file written as

```
a,b,c,d,e ...
```

how do I read this in python and rearrange as below format?

```
a
b
c
d
e
```

Many thanks..

Answer (score 1):

If you just wanna transpose you can use:

```
pd.read_csv('<Name of your csv file here>', header= None).T.to_csv('test.txt', index =False, header =None)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> pd.Series(open("dummy.txt").read().rstrip().split(','))
0    a
1    b
2    c
3    d
4    e
dtype: object
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.